# Photoshop 5.5 won't start after upgrading to windows 7 from vista

Tags: windows-7, adobe-photoshop

I have photoshop 5.5 working just fine under windows vista, I upgraded my PC to windows 7 and when I start photoshop 5.5 it just hangs.

I see the main screen open but nothing happens and I just get the busy sign out of the mouse pointer, with Photoshop not completing the start.

I searched online and some reported the same issue and were able to solve the issue by deleting Photoshop setting or preference file. I did that, but still the issue is present.

Comment: Photoshop 5.5 was released in 1999. Do you mean Photoshop CS5.5 (2011)?

Comment: Yes this is photoshop 5.5 not CS5.5

Answer (score 0):

It probably is a dll version problem. Before launching right click on the icon and select properties. Go to the compatibility tab and check "Run this program in compatibility mode for:" and choose Windows Vista.

If this doesn't work you can try reinstalling the program.

Comment: I tried this already before posting the question, to no luck.

Comment: @NeverDream did you try doing a clean install?

Comment: No. I am afraid I will not be able to do a new install, because others have reported that they couldn't install PS 5.5 in windows7. But at this point I think I have to do a re-install.

Comment: I did re-install but worked on the first day only after that it's back to the same problem where it won't start

Answer (score 0):

There might be a problem in the takeover of the programs when upgrading to Windows7
**Just 2 months ago I did a fresh installation of Photoshop 5.5 in Windows 7, there was no problem, it works just fine.**
Just a pity it's work for nothing. 
Good luck with your new install.